# Suppress space around inline xymatrix

Tags: spacing, xy-pic, xymatrix

An inline `xymatrix` is, by default, surrounded by a non-0 amount of space:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
[\(\xymatrix{A}\)] vs.\ [\(A\)]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Illustration of spacing around xymatrix]

How do I adjust (in fact remove) that spacing?  Edited to add, after @Sebastiano's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689023): if possible, I'd like to do this by some appropriate `\setlength` or by passing some appropriate argument to `xymatrix`, rather than by manually adding spacing commands before or after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several (somewhat cryptic) commands in `xy` to adjust spacing. See section 3.3 of [the manual](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf) for details. In your case I think you want to set the margin (`@M`) to `0pt`.

There is also the "special code" `@1` that is designed for "one-line" diagrams to improve the placement on the line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
[\(\xymatrix@M=0pt{A}\)] vs.\ [\(A\)] vs.\ [\(\xymatrix@1{A}\)]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always with the best answers, this answers the question I asked, as well as the one I probably should have asked.  Thanks!